# How to run a function several times but run the instruction list only once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I made a program with several buttons and I wish that when I press the button several times, the list of instructions only launches once.

I tried to do it with a global variable but when I want to use the same variable for both screens, I can’t do it.

I know I can do it using two global variables but I would like to use the same one in both screens.

How, when we get to the second screen, u takes the value "True"? Or is there a simpler solution with a decorator?

Here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import random
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition


kv = """

#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition     
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import RiseInTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition
#: import CardTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.CardTransition

MyScreenManager:
    transition: RiseInTransition()
    Question1:
        name: "question1"
    Question2:
        name: "question2"


<Question1>:

    label_wid : ratio

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            text: "+1"
            pos: 270, 300
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press:
                root.mauvais()
        Button:
            text: "following"
            pos: 270, 240
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press: 
                Clock.schedule_once(root.suite, 0.75)

        Label:
            id: ratio
            text: root.manager.theText 
            pos: 280,270
            font_size: 17
            color: 0,0,1,0.65

<Question2>:
    label_wid2: ratio
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "+1"
            pos: 270, 300
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press:
                root.mauvais()

        Label:
            id: ratio
            text: root.manager.theText
            pos: 280,270
            font_size: 17
            color: 0,0,1,0.65


"""

t=0 
m=True



class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    theText = StringProperty('')  


class Question1(Screen):

    m= True
    def mauvais(self):
        global m
        if  m==True:
            global t
            t=t+1
            self.manager.theText = str(t)
            m=False        

    def suite(root,text):
        root.manager.current = "question2"

    pass 

class Question2(Screen):    

    global m
    m= True
    def mauvais(self):
        global m
        if  m==True:
            global t
            t=t+1
            self.manager.theText = t
            m=False     
    pass



class Quizz(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Quizz'
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 1, 1, 0.25)

        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Quizz().run()
```

Comment: When you say "when I press the button several times, the list of instructions only launches once", do you mean once ever, or are you talking about pressing the button several times within a specific time period?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since I didn't get an answer to my question, I have a proposed solution that does both possibilities:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, NumericProperty
kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition


kv = """

#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition     
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import RiseInTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition
#: import CardTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.CardTransition

MyScreenManager:
    transition: RiseInTransition()
    Question1:
        name: "question1"
    Question2:
        name: "question2"


<Question1>:

    label_wid : ratio

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            text: "+1"
            pos: 270, 300
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press:
                root.manager.mauvais()  # method is now in MyScreenManager
        Button:
            text: "following"
            pos: 270, 240
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press: 
                Clock.schedule_once(root.suite, 0.75)

        Label:
            id: ratio
            text: root.manager.theText
            pos: 280,270
            font_size: 17
            color: 0,0,1,0.65

<Question2>:
    label_wid2: ratio
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "+1"
            pos: 270, 300
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press:
                root.manager.mauvais()  # method is now in MyScreenManager

        Label:
            id: ratio
            text: root.manager.theText
            pos: 280,270
            font_size: 17
            color: 0,0,1,0.65
"""

#  time to ignore additional clicks
#  if this is zero, ignore all additional clicks
CLICK_IGNORE_TIME = 3

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    theText = StringProperty('')
    m = BooleanProperty(True)
    t = NumericProperty(0)

    def mauvais(self):
        if  self.m==True:
            self.t += 1
            self.theText = str(self.t)
            self.m=False
            if CLICK_IGNORE_TIME > 0:
                Clock.schedule_once(self.reset_m, CLICK_IGNORE_TIME)
        else:
            print('ignored click')

    def reset_m(self, dt):
        print('reset m')
        self.m = True


class Question1(Screen):
    def suite(root,text):
        root.manager.current = "question2"


class Question2(Screen):
    pass


class Quizz(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Quizz'
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 1, 1, 0.25)

        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Quizz().run()
```

This code moves the `mauvais()` method to the `MyScreenManager` class, since both versions were identical.

The `CLICK_IGNORE_TIME` is how long to ignore additional clicks. If it is zero all additional clicks will be ignored

Comment: Thank you so much. If we remove CLICK_IGNORE_TIME, how to reset the value of m when changing the screen?

Comment: For simplicity, I moved my suite() function into the screenmanager()  class and added the self.m=True line: it's almost than reset_m() function. But when suite() is called, I have the error: `suite() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' ` why plz ? (sorry for my english ;) )

Comment: Can't tell without seeing what you have done. Please post a separate question for this issue.